# How do I brew longjing tea?

Tags: tea

I want some knowledge regarding the longjing tea.

I have not tasted it but want some more knowledge about it and also the brewing method of it.

Comment: I'm sorry, we don't deal with health questions here. We can certainly address the brewing of the tea, but not anything having to do with potential health benefits.

Comment: I edited the question to remove references to health benefits. That done, I also retracted my vote to close.

Comment: @Jolenealaska, must be a tough place to work when according to their profile they're a manager at the above store and they don't get a cup to try.

Answer (score 2):

Brewing method is pretty standard, like most green teas: 80 deg Celsius, let it steep for a few minutes.

Comment: Even this is too hot for many good quality green teas.  A reasonable longjing releases more interesting flavours if steeped at 60-70°C; 80°C destroys some of the more subtle notes.  Try several different temperatures to see which works best for the specific tea.

Answer (score 2):

Longjing tea is a green tea. So the general principals of brewing green tea apply:

***The tea leaf to water ratio***: Around 3 g of tea leaves for 150ml of water.

***Water temperature*** is very important to bring out the best in a green tea. Not sure if you've had green tea before, but if the water temperature is too hot or boiling, the tea will brewed bitter and will lose much of its delicate aroma. On the other hand, if it not hot enough, the brewed tea will not be full flavored.

***For the first and second steeping***, the tea leaves should be brewed in hot water at 70°c - 80°c for 1 minute. You can always experiment with the length to find out your desired flavor.

***For subsequent brewing***, if reusing the same leaves, increase steeping time and temperature.

Notes, the easiest way I personally find to reach this desired temperature (75°c), at least in a cup, is to fill 3/4th cup with hot water and 1/4th with cold water, a tip shared by a tea shop employee.